# Update User List coffee

Tags: coffeescript

I have my chat in html5 and i have this code to handle new user that enter in my meeting:

```
# Add a user to the screen.
_addUser: (userID, username) ->
  data =
    username: username
    userID: userID
  compiledTemplate = _.template(userTemplate, data)
  @$el.children("ul").append compiledTemplate
```

I have try to see to manual of coffee but nothing.

But if i am the first to enter in the chat, i see all that enter after me, if i am the last to enter in the chat, i don't see nobody. Why? Where i wrong?

Comment: Why would you see anything that happened before? There's nothing there that would initialize a user list to contain the people already present.

Comment: I agree with mu here, it seems like it's behaving properly based on description.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in assuming that `_addUser()` is called when a new user enters the chat? If so, is it called for every user *already in the chat*? Because the way you describe it, it appears that only new users get rendered into the `ul`.